# Lists files from svn ignoring directories (webMethods)

Tags: svn, webmethods

In my webMethods flow I got public service "executeOSCommand". In the flow I am passing arguments:

svn ls --xml svn+ssh://myURL/

It returns .sql files from reposotory, but also one directory. What argument should I pass, to ignore the one directory, so output only would show the .sql files? Thanks!

Comment: Is it really "ls --xml ..." or did you mean "svn ls --xml ..."?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It starts with "svn ls --xml..."